# rdp dynamic channels plugin through rd-gateway

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I want to develop a plugin for rdp which is using dynamic virtual channels.
Is it possible to use a plugin which is using dynamic virtual channels through an RD-Gateway?
Or is there some kind of whitelist on the RD-Gateway, which needs to be edited to allow such a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research in this topic I found, that it is possible, but when you are sending data from the server to the client, the [VirtualChannelOpenEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483734(v=winembedded.60).aspx) will be called twice. So the data will be sent twice.